# Redirect and apply color from text file

Tags: batch-file

I just started coding with Batch a couple weeks ago, a couple hours a day while at work.

I'm writing a script to auto-launch and auto-create dated files. I thought it would be nice to try something "fun".

What I'm trying to do is have my main script save a configuration file with the Batch color code to call upon later/first start and change itself to the previously saved color code. Preferably with a text file.

I've tried using the global variable thing. I think our IT has that disabled as I cannot share variable states between scripts. I haven't tried to enable it. I should also mention we are on Windows 7.

I have since gone the route of creating a `colors.bat` with the below example code within. I have applied the redirection to my main script to save the file after asking the user for a color code that gets applied to a variable. Right now this Batch file is called upon at a first start in the main script, later I will add a statement to check if the file exists or not.

```
color 5e
```

Instead I would prefer a text file that can be called upon or perhaps even a file without a container to prevent backend editing.

However I can't seem to get my script to apply the code inside the text file properly. Below are examples that have failed to apply the color change. Inside the "colors.txt" file is just the Batch compatible color code of "5e" and nothing else.

```
type colors.txt | color
echo Test

color <colors.txt
echo Test
```

The above code I have tried with varying placements of the spaces as well.

I've been at this for a few hours now reading up on Batch and Redirection and really anything else of interest. I tried at one point putting the color code as the file name and then trying the Parameter stuff like " %~n1 ". I couldn't figure that out at all.

I hope none of that was confusing. But I'll reiterate, the script as it is right now works. I want to use a `.txt` container instead of `.bat` or better yet no container at all. Or even get the global variables enabled, whichever is the best route. I want to call upon this file at script start to apply the color code.

If you have any other questions let me know. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is fairly straight forward

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
if exist colors.txt (
    goto setcolor
) else (
    set /p color="Choose color: "
    echo !color! > colors.txt
    attrib colors.txt +r
    endlocal
    goto setcolor
)
:setcolor
for /F %%i in (colors.txt) do color %%i
echo Test
pause
```

The above code check if `colors.txt` exists, if not it will prompt you for a preferred colour and background colour. Save the code to file and then set it, next time the file will be found and it will just set the colour without re-prompting. We also set `attrib +r` to make file read-only, if you want to prevent people from editing it, there are ways around it though.

EDIT:
`enabledelayedexpansion` do `cmd /?` and you will see

> /V:ON
>
> Enable delayed environment variable expansion using ! as the
>           delimiter. For example, /V:ON would allow !var! to expand the
>           variable var at execution time.  The var syntax expands variables
>           at input time, which is quite a different thing when inside of a FOR
>           loop.

Comment: What does the ! do for the variable? So far I've just been using the command-line references on the technet.microsoft.com website. Doesn't  have everything but it's gotten me this far. 

Even if the file is set to read-only Batch can still edit it correct?

Comment: @offroadguy56 You will get loads of help from cmd.exe by simply running `cmd /?` and each of the topics you can then do `/?` on for instance `for /?` or `if /?`, `setlocal /?` etc etc.